# Visualforce Invalid session in Salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app

Hi I have a action on custom object that uses a custom Visualforce page.

After the device is idle for a while, I get this error when I tried to select a contact lookup on the page, or click on the save button on the page:

> The page you submitted was invalid for your session. Please click save again to confirm your changes.

To fix the error, I will either need to log out salesforce1 or go to other records and refresh the page by scrolling down the page until more fields are loaded to get the session back.

Any one having this issue? I tried set the cache to both true and false on the VF page. No difference. I even added a timer on the page to call remote action every minute. I can see the call in debug log. But when I try to select the lookup field on the page or click on save, I get the invalid session error.